# Gamescene.sks and GameScene.swift don't seem to be linked in my project

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I am learning SpriteKit and started a small project using the level editor.

However, the GameScene.swift and GameScene.sks don't seem to be linked for some reason. Below are the screenshots for the .sks file setup and a small print statement in viewDidLoad of the .swift file. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Or if I am missing something.

[image: SKS File.]

The spritekit .sks file.

[image: Swift File]

[image: Output]

My View Controller's viewDidLoad function.

```
    class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let screenSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        GameController.gameController.setGameManager(gameViewManager: self);

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would help to show where you init GameScene. Usually in a view controller and what shows when you actually run the app?

Comment: @SkylerLauren, Done. When I run the app, the GameScene from the sks file runs. However, the script from the .swift file doesn't run.

Comment: Everything appears to be correct. I would look in the GameScene.swift file. Might be something silly in there like GameScene typed wrong or something. Also does autocomplete give you GameScene as an option when typing it in the SKS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a normal `GameScene.swift` that should be print "hello" with his `GameScene.sks` called by a `GameViewController`. You did not specify what is `GameController` but this is not a problem because I think you could simply lost the flow of your game so I try to help you about it (dont' worry, 
it happens when you are focused on the rest of the game a long time and can not remember the starting flow).

In your `Main.storyboard` you probably don't have a situation like this:

[image]

[image]

where your `GameViewController` **is the initial view controller**.
What I mean is you should check who call `GameViewController` on your storyboard or if your `AppDelegate.swift` (in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) stop the flow or call other views before calling `GameViewController`.

So , check who is the **IVC** (initial view controller) and be sure your `GameViewController` is called from start or by other viewControllers using breakpoint or simply launch this print in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
print("∙ \(type(of: self))")
```

---

Another situation could be happen when you add or remove files with the same name in library. In this case try to remove `GameScene.swift` and `GameScene.sks`, clean and build your project and re-add these files (be sure as your screen GameScene.sks have the right custom class..)
Check your **Compile Sources** list to control your `GameScene.swift`

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: @allessandro I checked what you said. I printed a statement in GameViewController's didMove to View function. It worked fine and printed that statement to the console. I tried removing the reference and adding it again. I checked the compile sources and custom classes.

Comment: the Custom Class is important to link your swift to sks: sometimes it don't work because it don't see the correct swift module (an old or cached wrong version..). Check and correct it until it see the module.

Comment: Thank you! I had to check all the stuff again to make sure. For some reason, it converts hyphen to underscore in the module name.

Comment: Great shot, good news.Well, it happen sometimes, happy to know that is solved. Good luck for your project.